# Beautiful Soup: get picture size from html

Tags: python, image, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the pictures' widths and heights using Bueatiful Soup. All pictures have the same code format:

```
<img src="http://somelink.com/somepic.jpg" width="200" height="100">
```

I can extract the links easily with

```
for pic in soup.find_all('img'):
    print (pic['src'])
```

But

```
for pic in soup.find_all('img'):
    print (pic['width'])
```

is not working for extracting sizes. What am I missing?

**EDIT:**
One of the pictures in the page does not have the width and height in the html code. Did not notice this at the time of the initial post. So any solution must take this into account

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dictionary-like attribute access should work for `width` and `height` as well, if they are specified. You might encounter images that don't have these attributes explicitly set - your current code would throw a `KeyError` in this case. You can use `get()` and provide a default value instead:

```
for pic in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(pic.get('width', 'n/a'))
```

Or, you can find only `img` elements that have the `width` and `height` specified:

```
for pic in soup.find_all('img', width=True, height=True):
    print(pic['width'], pic['height'])
```

Comment: There is a picture without explicit width and height, but `get()` returns `None` for that particular picture

Comment: @horace_vr sure, if width is not set, `pic.get('width')` would return `None`. As opposed to a `KeyError` in case of `pic['width']`.

Answer (score 1):

It works a little differently, to get other attributes

```
for pic in soup.find_all('img'):
    print(pic.get('width'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
>>> html = '<img src="http://somelink.com/somepic.jpg" width="200" height="100">'
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for tag in soup.find_all('img'):
...     print tag.attrs.get('height', None), tag.attrs.get('width', None)
... 
100 200
```

you can use attrs method, it returns a dict , keys as attribute of tag and values as tag value .