# How to find the biggest images in scraped pages via beautifulsoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I want to find the image that best represents a web page.

My code is :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #Import stuff
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.test.com/") #Download website source

data = r.text  #Get the website source as text

soup = BeautifulSoup(data) #Setup a "soup" which BeautifulSoup can search

links = []

for link in soup.find_all('img'):  #Cycle through all 'img' tags
    imgSrc = link.get('src')   #Extract the 'src' from those tags
    links.append(imgSrc)    #Append the source to 'links'

print(links)  #Print 'links'
```

I know this three method might be useful:

> ```
> Check for Open Graph/Twitter Card tags
> Find the largest suitable image on the page
> Look for a suitable video thumbnail if no image is found
> ```

I want to get biggest images in pages based on their dimensions.

I did a research on this but I couldn't find something good and fast executable.

Comment: Have you looked at [Beautiful Soup: get picture size from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36754686/beautiful-soup-get-picture-size-from-html)

Comment: Dear @rassar, I have seen the page before it's just usable when the width and height attributes defined and unfortunately in most of times it's not defined.

Comment: Then, unfortunately you can't use BeautifulSoup for this because beautifulsoup can't read live DOM attributes. Have a look at selenium - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15510882/selenium-get-coordinates-or-dimensions-of-element-with-python

Comment: Okay, but what about use other python libraries to check all the images for dimension? I think it's not good for speed of algorithm.

Comment: Is this possible to working on every img tags that's located into p tags as post images?

Comment: And also this link is might be usable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51116907/beatifulsoup-how-to-get-image-size-by-url , but I want to find away to get the image dimensions without download all images using their css informations.